# Unknown source locking domain administrator account and trying random usernames

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, malware, authentication

On my domain I have a virtual machine which I can see an unknown source is constantly attempting to authenticate.

I can stop it by blocking the RPC ports on the local firewall of the VM, but that causes a ton of trouble for me.

When I check my `netlogon.log` file it looks like this for the administrator logout

> 11/29 13:47:32 [LOGON] [4100] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network
>   logon of (null)\ADMINISTRATOR from  (via MyVirtualMachineHostname)
>   Returns 0xC000006A 11/29 13:49:36 [LOGON] [5364] COMPANY: SamLogon:
>   Transitive Network logon of (null)\ADMINISTRATOR from  (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC000006A 11/29 13:52:32 [LOGON]
>   [6436] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of
>   (null)\Administrator from WIN-L1JIA2E591R (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC000006A 11/29 13:52:40 [LOGON]
>   [6436] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of
>   TRENDSALES\Zucchini from 'MyPCHostname' (via MyVirtualMachineHostname)
>   Returns 0xC000006A 11/29 14:02:34 [LOGON] [5364] COMPANY: SamLogon:
>   Transitive Network logon of (null)\ADMINISTRATOR from  (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC000006A 11/29 14:04:16 [LOGON]
>   [1216] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of
>   (null)\Administrator from WIN-L1JIA2E591R (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC000006A 11/29 14:14:34 [LOGON]
>   [5364] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of
>   (null)\ADMINISTRATOR from  (via MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns
>   0xC000006A 11/29 14:16:02 [LOGON] [5364] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive
>   Network logon of (null)\Administrator from WIN-L1JIA2E591R (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC000006A 11/29 14:18:11 [LOGON]
>   [3628] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of
>   (null)\ADMINISTRATOR from  (via MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns
>   0xC000006A 11/29 14:27:50 [LOGON] [5364] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive
>   Network logon of (null)\Administrator from WIN-L1JIA2E591R (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC000006A 11/29 14:33:47 [LOGON]
>   [2244] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of
>   (null)\ADMINISTRATOR from  (via MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns
>   0xC000006A 11/29 14:37:41 [LOGON] [892] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive
>   Network logon of (null)\ADMINISTRATOR from  (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC000006A 11/29 14:41:18 [LOGON]
>   [7012] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of
>   (null)\Administrator from WIN-L1JIA2E591R (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC000006A

It also attempts a large range of random usernames looking like this:

> 11/29 14:28:12 [LOGON] [3884] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network
>   logon of (null)\RCSSupport from FreeRDP (via MyVirtualMachineHostname)
>   Returns 0xC0000064 11/29 14:28:16 [LOGON] [3884] COMPANY: SamLogon:
>   Transitive Network logon of (null)\RCSSupport from FreeRDP (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC0000064 11/29 14:28:35 [LOGON]
>   [7120] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of (null)\pos from
>   FreeRDP (via MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC0000064 11/29
>   14:28:47 [LOGON] [4436] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of
>   (null)\pos from FreeRDP (via MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns
>   0xC0000064 11/30 11:53:04 [LOGON] [3048] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive
>   Network logon of (null)\MSSQLSERVER from  (via
>   MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC0000064 11/30 11:54:19 [LOGON]
>   [3048] COMPANY: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of (null)\IUSR_QA
>   from  (via MyVirtualMachineHostname) Returns 0xC0000064

How do I find out where the attempts are coming from? It looks like the hostname is being spoofed?

I'm also not sure if the problem is malware on the machine `MyVirtualMachineHostname` or if I’m looking for an infected computer on my network.

Comment: Did you shutdown the VM `MyVirtualMachineHostname` to see whenever it stops?

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out what TCP (and/or UDP) ports are being used.  My guess is TCP port 135, but I believe RPC can be a tricky thing, possibly using other ports.  If your firewall lets you disable those ports by specifying certain rules, then look at those rules to see what ports are involved.

Then, look for active connections.  One way is via a command line.  Here are the commands for the traditional command line:

```
netstat -na
netstat -na | find /i "135" | more
```

(If using PowerShell, you would need to place a back tick/quote before each of those quotation marks.)

Another way: In Windows 10 (and maybe as early as Vista?), right-click on the task bar, choose Task Manager.   On the Performance Tab, click "Resource Manager".  (Or, there may be some other ways to get to that Resource Manager.)  Go to the Network tab, and expand the "TCP Connections" section (preferred).  Or, if UDP is involved, the "Listening Ports" section might have more info.

What this does is to start identifying the IP address of the attacker.  Once you have that, you may not be able to get more information unless you start interacting with that machine.  (You may need permissions on that machine to find more details.)  Well, you could get more information by sniffing the network connection (e.g., with TCPDump or the more graphical Wireshark), but you're better off trying to use that machine (via it's keyboard, or through remote management tools like Computer Management or WMIC).

If the remote IP address is loopback (starts with "127." for IPv4, or is "::1" for IPv6), then you'll likely have two entries (one for the outgoing connection, and one for the receiving connection).  In that case, run `netstat -nab` from a command prompt.  Make sure that command prompt is elevated (if you have UAC enabled).  That will give you a PID that can be used to identify which local program is being used.  To do that, from an elevated command prompt, use:

```
WMIC PROCESS GET Name,ProcessID /FORMAT:LIST
```

(Again, PowerShell users place a back-tick, this time before the comma.)  (For more info, leave off the "Name,ProcessID" part.)  For a specific ProcessID/PID, e.g. 12345, you could use:

```
WMIC PROCESS GET Name,ProcessID /FORMAT:TABLE | FIND /I "12345"
```